# Binding LinqDataSource from code-behind to Gridview

Tags: asp.net, linqdatasource

i have a grdidview control on the .aspx page and i am trying to connect dynamically from code behind and bind the gridview but somehow it throwing me an error... what is wrong with this code? any help?

```
  LinqDataSource LDS_POReport = new LinqDataSource();
            LDS_POReport.ContextTypeName = "DataContextDataContext";
            LDS_POReport.Selecting += new EventHandler<LinqDataSourceSelectEventArgs>(LinqDataSourcePO_Selecting);
            this.gvReport.DataSource = "LDS_POReport";
            //this.gvReport.DataBind();
```

Update:

after i update the code to

```
 this.gvReport.DataSource = LDS_POReport;
```

it works fine but when i try to sort i get this error:

**The GridView 'gvReport' fired event Sorting 
which wasn't handled.**

i added this but no effect.

```
 LDS_POReport.AutoPage = true;
 LDS_POReport.AutoSort = true;
```

Comment: When asking a question like this, please *always* include exception details. "It throws an error" is not very much to draw any conclusions from.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I *guess* that your problem is here:

```
this.gvReport.DataSource = "LDS_POReport";
```

The above code line attempts to assign a string to a property that expects some sort of data source. I assume that you really intended to assign the `LinqDataSource` object itself:

```
this.gvReport.DataSource = LDS_POReport;
```

Comment: Fred, it works but sorting/paging does not work i get this error "The GridView 'gvReport' fired event Sorting which wasn't handled"

Comment: @Nishar: when `AllowSorting` is `true` you need to set up an event handler for the `Sorting` event. It seems that no such event handler is present.

Answer (score 0):

First thing, the DataSource should get a reference to the object containing the data, not the name of the object containing the data. GridViews can work reflectively, but not THAT reflectively.