# vb listview - reading a value into a string

Tags: asp.net, sql, vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I've searched thoroughly before asking, I'd like to find out how to take some text from a listview and pass it into a string. Theres only one column in the listview and only one row. The value in it is an integer.

The closest I came was this:

```
teststring = ListView1.Items.ToString
```

but that just filled the string with "System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListViewDataItem]"

Update: I'm working under ASP.NET

Comment: Yes I have tried it. Thank you for the suggestion. I commented below what happened.

Comment: @SATSON I am using a linqdatasource to get an integer from an sql table, I didn't code anything.

Comment: it is totally empty until a button press, then there is one integer and nothing else

Comment: listview show anything in run time. then select value and get the index in selection changed and use that index for get value

Comment: i'm not sure i follow?

Comment: Try it. because listview.item(0) is index out of range means i think listview does have items so first check which value passing in selection changed event then use that for get value. just try it may be helpful. All is Well

Comment: I will try it, but I didn't understand what you meant, but now I think I do. I think you are right. I've been looking at it for a long time now and I agree that there must be no data in the listview. I'm getting data from an SQL table when a button is pressed, and its the same button that tries to read the gridview. I think I need to implement the gridview on another page using the suggestions that have been made here. I will update with results and confirm which Answer worked

Comment: listview. i have tried both though, and they both seem to have nothing in them.

Comment: if you want gridview then try [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3670549/binding-linqdatasource-from-code-behind-to-gridview) and get value using follwing code  `GridView1.Rows(0).Cells(0).Text`

Comment: After taking the data to another page, doing a linqdatasource and gridview there, the code: labelText = GridView1.Rows(0).Cells(0).Text successfully works. However the code labelText = ListView1.DataMember(1) did not.

Comment: i knew that already. anyway happy coding. check my previus code `listview.items(0).ToString` :)

Comment: Thanks alot for your help. I can't mark a right answer because the listview never worked. I'm using gridview instead.

Answer (score 0):

Use this,

```
teststring =  ListView1.Items(ListView1.Items.Count - 1)
```

Instead of

```
teststring = ListView1.Items.ToString
```

Because your attempt will get the ListViewItemCollection (Non-Technically: group of items), But actually your need is to get a single item from that group. If you need further clarifications, Please refer [this.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.items.aspx)

Update,

```
 teststring =  Ctype(ListView1.Items(ListView1.Items.Count - 1),Control).text
```

Comment: Thankyou. The code was underlined in blue and said cannot be converted to string, so I amended it like this: testtext = (ListView1.Items(ListView1.Items.Count - 1)).ToString  It now passes this string into testtext "System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListViewDataItem"

Comment: @user2247353 Oh, ok just try my new update, and commnent back if it isworking for you :)

Comment: It is underlined blue and says 'text' is not a member of 'System.Web.UI.Control'. Tried loading the page anyway but it showed an error with the line highlighted. I am using visual studio 2010 and vb. Do I need to import something for it to work?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
teststring = ListView1.Items(0).Text
```

Comment: It gives compilation error 'Text' is not a member of 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListViewDataItem'. Its like I'm missing an Import statement or something. I am using visual studio 2010 and vb

Comment: Nah, this works for standart winforms ListView, but you must be working under ASP.NET without telling us.